# HttpClient Polly Timeout Policy

Tags: c#, timeout, httpclient, polly

The get request is waiting longer than the `timeoutPolicy` to timeout.

- Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
- Why does the request not timeout at 30ms?

```cs
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30), TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);
var watch = new Stopwatch();
try
{
    watch.Start();
    var httpResponse = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
        async ct => await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://google.com"), ct),
        CancellationToken.None
    );
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("request took " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("timeout took " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: it looks like `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` requires the `CancellationToken` to be used, otherwise if you can't trust the `CancellationToken` then it will work with `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`.
Try passing the `CancellationToken` to `SendAsync`

Comment: Cancellation token i.e. ct is passed to SendAsync. It does throw the timeout exception but it is taking longer than 30 ms around 90 ms to throw it.

Comment: I suspect that the `CancellationToken` being passed in is actually the `CancellationToken.None` that you specify next. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: My testing is all being done with arbitrary `Task.Run()` and no cancellation occurs when I test. So it's probably a different scenario and I've not replicated it correctly. If you get the timeout but a bit delayed, perhaps Polly just isn't as precise as you'd want, though that said I'm clearly no expect on this topic so hopefully somebody else can help.

Comment: I copied the code line for line into a test and can confirm  that the first few times I ran this, I got a 90ms delay. After that though I started getting 30ms timeouts consistently.
Perhaps theres other stuff going on that add to the timer unexpectedly. e.g. The time it takes to spin up a thread while the stopwatch is timing but before the thread begins executing. Or even just garbage collection can add delays between starting and stopping the stopwatch.

Comment: Another interesting observation is that when I change the webpage, I get the 90ms delay again the first time, and then 30ms after that. Maybe some DNS lookups or something adding overhead the first time a new domain is hit?

Comment: Yet another fun observation, using a domain that does not exist has spiked from like 250ms to over a second as it resolves the first time, but then drops to 0 to 1ms after the lookup has been cached. I think this is going to related to lookups and caches somehow.

Comment: @YogiInt Did you try to increase the timeout (for example to 500ms) and then measure the timeout delay?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've played around with it enough that I know what's going on, So I feel confident that I can now answer the question.

When you invoke the `async` task with `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` Polly strategy, you are passing in a `CancellationToken` and essentially trusting that the `CancellationToken` will be invoked to end the task in a timeout scenario.

Unlike the behavior with the `TimeoutStrategy.Pesimistic` strategy which is designed to be able to terminate a syncronous task which does not callback via the `CancellationToken`.

While your main execution thread is not blocked by an asyncronous task running on another thread, it's important to remember that the task is indeed able to block it's own thread.

For example, If an async task were to call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` then it's thread would be blocked for a second. Which in turn means that the `CancellationToken` cannot be invoked for the duration of the block.

In this scenario I believe that long running operations such as looking up the DNS record for a hostname the first time, or any other blocking operation is occurring which is essentially blocking the thread for 90ms.

As such, even though the task knows that it needs to be aborted at the 30ms mark, it need to wait for the thread to be available before it can actually invoke the cancellation, which doesn't occur until about 90ms or thereabouts.

This delay in returning a timeout only seems to occur the first time for each domain resolution, so I presume this is related to nameserver caching and DNS resolution as subsequent calls seem to honor the timeout more efficiently. Although asserting any direct root cause is largely speculation.